# Ubuntu 16.04 php 7.0 apache not working

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I am trying to get this to work and am having no luck here is my apache config any help with what is wrong would be appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@qis.net
  ServerName www.site.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/www.site.com/httpdocs
  ScriptAlias "cgi-bin" "/var/www/sites/www.site.com/cgi-bin"

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site.com.error_log

  LogLevel debug

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.site.com.log combined


    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>

    AddHandler php7-fcgi-kermit .php
    Action php7-fcgi-kermit /php7-fcgi-kermit
    Alias /php7-fcgi-kermit /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-kermit
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-kermit -socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.kermit.sock -pass-header Authorization

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    </IfModule>


  <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
      SetHandler php7-fcgi-kermit
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

The site is not working at all and not even throwing an error in the log. It did throw this error yesterday

AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/sites/www.site.com/php7-fcgi/wp-admin/install.php

**Update:**

I disabled the 000-default site and only left the vhost and now it is logging this error.

```
[Tue Mar 20 13:57:40.661109 2018] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7060:tid 140644508116736] (13)Permission denied: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49471] FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-kermit": connect() failed
[Tue Mar 20 13:57:40.661130 2018] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7060:tid 140644508116736] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49471] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-kermit
```

I changed the php part of the conf to read as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>

AddHandler php7-fcgi .php  
Action php7-fcgi /php7-fcgi  
Alias /php7-fcgi-kermit /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-kermit  
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-kermit -socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.kermit.sock -pass-header Authorization

<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
Require all granted
</Directory>
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
```

After I did this I get the following error but fpm is running and the fastcgi module is loaded

Error: PHP is not running

Any ideas?

Comment: What is not working? Is Apache throwing errors? Is FastCGI not working? Is mod_fastcgi enabled? Is the site not working at all? What does the error log show if so? [Edit] your question with the answers.

Comment: fpm seems to be running and so is apache but it is changing the DocumentRoot to contain php7-fcgi which should not be there